# Beginner - XML to XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and trying some sample applications, I found examples on XML to HTML and XML to XML conversion but I'm facing issue in XML to XML conversion using XSLT.

This is my source XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ref="articale.xsl"?>
<article>
  <title>the title</title>
  <para>a para para para para para</para>
</article>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org 1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="article">
    <foo><xsl:apply-templates/></foo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <foo.title><xsl:apply-templates/></foo.title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <foo.para><xsl:apply-templates/></foo.para>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is generating plain text like:

```
the title a para para para para para
```

Can somebody please help on this.

Steps I followed:

1. Created XSL file.
2. Included the XSLT file in the source XML that is here first one.
3. Accessed this in browser.

Please correct me if I'm doing wrongly the execution of this XML.

Comment: What tool/platform are you using to run the transform? How are you looking at the results?

Comment: "the title a para para para para para" is the output in your browser? Use the browser's View Source feature to see the raw XML and post that

Comment: I'm depending on mozilla only.

Comment: "the title a para para para para para" this is the output in the browser. the view source feture is showing like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="articale.xsl"?>
<article>
  <title> the title</title>
  <para> a para para para para para</para>
</article>

Comment: you can try [this](http://www.xmlper.com/) online editor

Comment: You did say what you see. You forgot to mention what you *want to see*. How should anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT transformation engines in the browsers assume that you want to generate HTML, and they then render the HTML. If your output is XML, and contains tags that mean nothing to the browser, then the rendering engine in the browser will typically ignore them.

If you're trying to become familiar with XSLT and play with its capabilities, then the browser isn't a very good playground. It "renders" the output, rather than showing you the output "as is", and most of the browsers are very bad at giving clear error messages when you get things wrong. Get yourself an IDE like oxygen, or if you want something cheap and cheerful, try KernowForSaxon. Or just use the command line if you're comfortable with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will try KernowForSaxon to get generated xml.